# Vlookup from another sheet using multiple columns

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have an excel workbook with 2 sheets.

Sheet 4 and Sheet 5:

Sheet 4 has the following columns:

```
  type  model   name        year
  U     acura   jane        1998
  D     honda   peter       2002
  U     bmz     fred        1993
```

Sheet 5 also has the same columns but with an additional column sales.

```
  type  model   name        sales
  U     acura   jane        2.3
  D     honda   peter       3.8
  U     bmz     fred        19
```

IN both the sheets, I created an additional column called "key" concatenating type-model-name (A2&B2&C2)

```
  type  model   name        year   key
  U     acura   jane        1998   Dacurajane
  D     honda   peter       2002   Dhondapeter
  U     bmz     fred        1993   Dbmzfred
```

To get the sales in Sheet1, I am giving the following vlookup.

```
     =VLOOKUP(E2|Sheet5!A2:F4|5|FALSE)
```

I looked at other similar answers, trimmed the columns and did what the recommendations were, but it still returns #N/A

Can anyone point out what my mistake it?

Thanks In advance.

Comment: The key in the lookup table needs to be the furthest left in the lookup range.  So on sheet5 it needs to be in column a then change the 5 to a 6.

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX/MATCH

`=INDEX(Sheet5!D:D, MATCH(E2, Sheet5!A:A&Sheet5!B:B&Sheet5!C:C, 0))`

Enter with Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Also I am assuming that the sales is in column D of Sheet5. If different, put the appropriate column in as first parameter to the INDEX function.

Also please consider using restricted range references in the match function,  instead of full column references - for speed & efficiency.

Answer (score -2):

on cell E1 you will have KEY on cell E2 you will place =CONCATENATE(A2,B2,C2,D2) Combines contents above into a phrase "DFocusManuel2016". That should work for the combine part just paste that and drag down as desired on E2.

You can cover the rest of the cell population by simply assigning links to the cells so on cell A2,B2,C2 and D1 you will have =SHEETNAME!Y10 which Y10 corresponds to the source cell and Sheet name to the source sheet.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the user wants to copy and paste each time if there are changing sales. Also that CONCATENATE formula is not really helpful here.

Comment: who said copy and paste? I said assign links to the cells they will auto populate, go on try it and if it does not work I will delete my post.